# Object #<Navigator> has no method 'getUserMedia'

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm trying to use the method getUserMedia() but in the moment I try to call it, the console returns me that error

"Object # has no method 'getUserMedia'"

Have you got any idea of why is this happening?

I'm using the latest version of Chrome

Comment: Please add whatever relevant code you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current versions of Chrome do not support unprefixed `navigator.getUserMedia`. You will need to check whether this feature is supported and try prefixed alternatives, such as `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia`, as well.

For details, see the sample code at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia --

```
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

navigator.getMedia (constraints, success, error);
```

And keep in mind that `navigator.getMedia` may *still* be undefined if the browser supports none of these methods. It's still a very new feature, and is not universally available.